# How to switch between languages in laravell

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, lang

I'm new to laravell and would like to understand how to switch between two Languages the best way.

My website only uses two languages. I want to build a simple language switcher.
Here is my HTML -> Which should display the language that I want to switch to. Not show the current language.

For example. If i am on [www.test.com/en](http://www.test.com/en) my html says

```
            <a class="lang-switch">German</a>
```

So when i click on it i land on

[www.test.com/de](http://www.test.com/de)

And now my html should say

```
                <a class="lang-switch">English</a>
```

Here is how i do my language routing.

```
Route::get('/{locale?}', function ($locale = null) {
    if (isset($locale) && in_array($locale, config('app.available_locales'))) {
        app()->setLocale($locale);
    }

    return view('home');
});

Route::get('/{locale?}/contact/', function ($locale = null) {

    if (isset($locale) && in_array($locale, config('app.available_locales'))) {
        app()->setLocale($locale);
    }

    return view('contact');
});
```

I need this switch to work on both websites since it's a static nav bar.

I register my locales in my `app.php` file

```
        'available_locales' => [
        'English' => 'en',
        'German' => 'de',
    ],
```

I created a Language Controller but i'm not sure how to implement or use it correctly.

```
    class LanguageController extends Controller
    {
      public function switchLang($lang)
        {
          if (array_key_exists($lang, Config::get('languages'))) {
             Session::put('applocale', $lang);
          }
          return Redirect::back();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`app()->setLocale("de")` to set the application language

`app()->getLocale()` to get the application language

you may need to check laravel documentations for a detailed description

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization